Getting oracle.SQL.CLOB@12c0350 when querying clob column in SQL
I have a XML response column in my database table. I am trying to use substr and instr functions to fetch only a particular string from the XML.
I have created a SQL query for this. For many rows, I am getting the correct string as the result but for some I am getting this:

oracle.SQL.clob.12c0350

What could be the reason for that?

Which client/application are you using? If it's your own then please include the code you're using. (Also why are you using instr/substr to handle XML instead of the built-int XML functions like XMLQuery and XMLTable?)

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: details of which client application (SQL Developer, SQL*Plus, PHP, Java, etc.) you are using to connect to the data base; the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for some sample data in your table; a minimal example of the code you are using to query the database; more detail of the issue/error; and the expected output for that sample data. At the moment it is very difficult to answer the question because we cannot see your data or code or the error and we have to guess at all three.
